# How to remove all letters between characters ( and ) in a string?

Tags: java

How to remove all letters between characters ( and ) in a string?

For example :

Hello i am(rino) happy with my life(may be) always => Hello i am happy with my life always

Am used

```
data[mPosition]=data[mPosition].replaceAll("(.*?)", "");
```

But i don't know why it's not working.

help me to find a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: `'('` and `')'` are special regexp characters. Try with `replaceAll("\\(.*?\\)", "")`

Comment: the "?" is useless in this case, right ?

Comment: Thanks @ZouZou i forgot that point. It worked thanks a lot. :)

Comment: @ZouZou you should make your comment an answer

Comment: What would you like to do in case of strings like `one (two) three (four) five`?

Comment: Is there a problem like that as Pam indicated ? @ZouZou

Comment: Yes, there is a problem. You need the *reluctant* quantifier `*?`. @Hacketo is wrong.

Comment: That's why I was asking.

Comment: @Hacketo '?' is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more generic way could be - `data[mPosition]=data[mPosition].replaceAll("\\(.*?\\)", "")`